# Google Analytics Service OAUTH Python + Pandas formatting

Tags: python, pandas, google-analytics

Does anyone have a solution for using google api oauth for service (aka public/private key) and pandas google analytics extension?

It seems like pandas google analytics is set up to use client secrets, which I set up. This is a helpful [article from yhat](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/pandas-google-analytics.html). But I need the oauth to use service...then pip in the results to pandas.

I successfully created a service object to talk to google analytics / core reporting API. But then the returned json is unwieldy so I want to leverage pandas to read into nice tables. I tried to read_json from the returned json at "dataTable" but that's not formatted correctly for pandas to ingest.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the read_ga function directly? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html#google-analytics

Comment: In other words, just trying to understand why you need service and not client secrets...